# get specific file from sorted files

Tags: scripting

meybe this is too simple but im new on unix.

i have a directory like  /home and in this directory i have 5 files like ;

/home/file1.csv

/home/file2.csv

/home/file3.csv

/home/file4.csv

/home/file5.csv

i want to display a file like , they must be ordered by date and i can display for example 3.file from that order ..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure if you want it to be ordered newest first or oldest first.

```
ls -t | head -3
```

will print the newest 3 files, and

```
ls -rt | head -3
```

will print the oldest 3 files.

And if you want to sort the result in access time (the commands above sort them in modification time), please use the following commands respectively.

```
ls -u | head -3
ls -ru | head -3
```

Comment: This is actually a better than what I had given.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned method by aifreedom is better than what I had earlier (shifted to the bottom)

@denso, to ignore the directories, you can do this.

```
ls -p | grep -v \/ | head -3
```

ls -p lists everything in the current directory with the directories followed by a "/"
grep -v \*symbol* takes a stream and filters out the inputs containing symbol (here, the words containing /)
head -3 will provide the first 3 from the list.

_***old*_**

I don't know if there is an easier way to do this, but this works

```
ls -t | xargs  | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

Comment: can u explain this syctax more detaily ?

Comment: ls -t sorts by time. piping it through xargs, you can give the output of ls -t as a list of arguments to awk. awk '{ print $3 }' prints the third argument which is the third in the sorted order (from ls -t).

Comment: i understand now :)
but is there any option that only files ll count as a result set

Comment: i mean i just need files to be order not subdirectories or any directory.